# Delivery read notification of SMS in ANDROID SDK

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sms, mms

I am making a **mass sms sender marketing tool** and i have encountered some problems with generating reports. I want to get notified **when a particulary sms is read by the possible client**, **like a read notification** in the `SMTP` protocol. In email marketing i could also use an white pixel in such way that when it is loaded, a read notification is sent to the server. How can i do that with **SMS/MMS** ?

I have read the documentation from the following `Android SDK` classes :

```
TelephonyManager
SmsManager
SmsMessage
```

and i didn't find something useful.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't. The best you can do with SMS is get a delivery report from your network, but that's not guaranteed to work for every network, and the definition of delivery varies.

Comment: what do you mean by `delivery report from your network` ? i don't understand ...

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "result". Some (most, really) networks can provide the sender with notification that a given message has been delivered. However, depending on the network, "delivered" could mean one of several different things; e.g. delivery to the recipient's device, delivery to the network service center, etc.

Comment: I just realized my last comment might be confusing. Check the link that follows, specifically the `sendTextMessage()` method. I'm referring to the `deliveryIntent` parameter. This will fire if the device is notified of delivery. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

Comment: i understand what you are trying to tell me, i also get `delivery notification` in my android os when a message is been sent, but i want to see who read it so i can show my client how many of those numbers are real and how many read his ad campaign, understand? also i will make a link and whoever enters that link, it will count as an CLICK, but only those with browser, smartphone and a internet connection will do that ...

Comment: Yeah, I know what you're trying to do, but you can't do that with SMS.

Comment: can i do it with mms? or a sms that have html or a link, or somethink? i need to find a way ...

Comment: Sure, you can always put a web link in the message that the user can click, but as you said, if the recipient's device doesn't have a data connection, it won't be of any use.